# error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'anyType' from assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: types, f#, f#-3.0

When Using Resizable array with any types i can't loop through that array , f# seems not to understand my preDefined Type .
here is a sample code :

```
type someData = { 
     Entry:string ; id:int } 
let datas = new ResizeArray<someData>()
let record1 = {someData.Entry = "hiLo" ;someData.id =1234 }
datas.Add(record1)
let record2 = {someData.Entry = "Lolo" ;someData.id =1224 }
datas.Add(record2)
let record3 = {someData.Entry = "Hihi" ;someData.id =1231 }
datas.Add(record3)
let nameOnly = new ResizeArray<string>()
for entries in datas do
    nameOnly.Add(entries.Entry)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your sample code in

```
type someData = 
    { Entry:string ; id:int } 

let datas = new ResizeArray<someData>()
let record1 = {someData.Entry = "hiLo" ;someData.id =1234 }
datas.Add(record1)
let record2 = {someData.Entry = "Lolo" ;someData.id =1224 }
datas.Add(record2)
let record3 = {someData.Entry = "Hihi" ;someData.id =1231 }
datas.Add(record3)
let nameOnly = new ResizeArray<string>()

let createEntries () =
    for entries in datas do
        nameOnly.Add(entries.Entry)
createEntries()
```

there is no problem. If you first enter the part of your code up to the for loop, and then the for loop, the code also runs. I think it has something to do with the type being put into a temp module of the interactive.

Comment: Thx , Your Code seems to fix the Problem , though i Honestly don't Understand :)
**I think it has something to do with the type being put into a temp module of the interactive**