# error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'Position' from assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: types, compiler-errors, f#, fsi

When I build my solution, everything goes fine.
However, when I try to run a script in the FSI I get the following:

```
error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'Position' from assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I tried to [browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943006/error-fs0193-internal-error-could-not-load-type-anytype-from-assembly-fsi-a) around but I still do not understand what is causing the error.
From MS connect, it seems that there was an [issue with the fsi compiler that has already been resolved](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789745/f-internal-error-could-not-load-type).

The code fragment where `Position` is defined looks like this:

```
type Position = 
    struct   
        val Shares: NrShares
        val BuyPrice: Price 
        new (nrShares: NrShares, buyPrice: float) = { Shares = nrShares; BuyPrice = buyPrice}

        /// Merge two positions.
        static member inline (+!) (one: Position, other: Position) =
            let addToPosition (one: Position) (other: Position) = 
                let nrShares = one.Shares + other.Shares
                let avgprice = (one.Shares * one.BuyPrice + other.Shares * other.BuyPrice) / nrShares
                Position (nrShares, avgprice)

            // Sell out or partially an existing position. Buy price is not updated
            let sellFromPosition (one: Position) (other: Position) = 
                let newShares = one.Shares - other.Shares
                Position (newShares, one.BuyPrice)

            if (sign(one.Shares) = sign(other.Shares))
            then addToPosition one other
            else sellFromPosition one other
end
```

What is the issue here? 
Thanks!

**EDIT ONE**

In my current setup, I have a fsx script `LoadScript.fsx` where I load the required dll files with the `#r` directive and then open the desired modules with the `#open` directive.

`LoadScript.fsx` is called by the main scripts where I code up the actual calculations.
The chain of fsx scripts allows me to hide boilerplate code. I just show the main scripts with the calculations to the clients and everything looks neater.

This "chain" of `fsx` scripts has been working. Until yesterday, when I added new modules from a new `.fs` file.

I am trying to isolate the section of the code that generates the issue.
This is quite hard because the `error` message does not point to a specific piece of code.

What is weird is that when I run directly `LoadScript.fsx` everything goes through without any issue.
Fsi compilation fails when I call `LoadScript.fsx` from another script:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#load "LoadScript.fsx"
#endif
```

What could be the reason for this weird behavior?
Any hint?

Comment: The obvious question is: is your compiler version more modern than the date of the fix in the bug report?

Comment: The bug was reported for VS12 update 2, the fixed planned for update 3, I am running VS12 update 4

Comment: issue that you've mentioned is a different one. For this problem it will be great if you can get a small repro and submit it to fsbugs@microsoft.com

Comment: @desco Hi, thanks for looking into this. I am trying to prepare a small repro but I am struggling to isolate the specific piece of code that generates the issue. Unfortunately the type `Position` is defined in the first module loaded while the modules that may trigger the error are the last one loaded. In those modules we define `types` that depend on `Position` after a long chain of dependencies. I have added an edit. Maybe gives some hints on the problem. Thanks!